# Low CPU usage on ubuntu 14.04 and nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04, intel

I have two servers running the exact same nodejs application. I am doing load testing and I can't figure out why one of my servers will not utilize more CPU and RAM.

It is much slower when load testing yet it is not even close to utilizing all the free CPU and memory.

If I run top during the load test, these are the numbers I am getting

```
 PID  User      PR   NI VIRT    RES     SHR  S   %CPU %MEM  TIME    COMMAND
 1308 ubuntu    20   0 1002524  87508   9788 S   5.3  4.3   0:03.06 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1307 ubuntu    20   0  925540  75288   9436 S   5.0  3.7   0:02.17 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1308 ubuntu    20   0  992076  77068   9788 S  14.0  3.8   0:03.48 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1307 ubuntu    20   0  937140  86904   9436 S   2.7  4.3   0:02.25 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1308 ubuntu    20   0 1012936  98000   9788 S  14.3  4.8   0:03.91 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1307 ubuntu    20   0  942940  92644   9436 S   1.0  4.5   0:02.28 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1307 ubuntu    20   0  943204  92976   9436 S   6.0  4.6   0:02.46 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1308 ubuntu    20   0 1011764  96804   9788 S   6.0  4.7   0:04.09 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1307 ubuntu    20   0  933644  83388   9436 S   8.6  4.1   0:02.72 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1308 ubuntu    20   0 1008720  93556   9788 S   5.3  4.6   0:04.25 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1308 ubuntu    20   0 1000184  85256   9788 S   8.6  4.2   0:04.51 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1307 ubuntu    20   0  944092  93988   9436 S   7.6  4.6   0:02.95 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1307 ubuntu    20   0  941748  91816   9436 S  15.0  4.5   0:03.40 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1308 ubuntu    20   0 1004832  90008   9788 S   1.3  4.4   0:04.55 nodejs                                                                                                                             
 1307 ubuntu    20   0  933460  82632   9436 S   9.0  4.1   0:03.67 nodejs
```

Running two processes I don't see memory getting above 4.7% and CPU is at 14%.

It is taking twice as long to serve the exact same resources as a machine with one core and half the memory.

My other server is using %52 of CPU. Granted it has one core and the above has two, but it doesn't seem like that would make the difference.

I downloaded cpufrequtils and set the GOVERNOR to performance but I don't think it is working. This is what I get when I run cpufreq-info

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 1:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
```

Here is the CPU

```
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU          6300  @ 1.86GHz
```

Any ideas or hints would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post the header portion of the top output?  It looks like you just posted the process info.  I suspect that your CPU is waiting on I/O.  You would see that in the header next to "wa" in the CPU summary.

Answer (score 0):

If both servers are running the same node.js application, then you may want to
compare the other settings on the machines, are they the same?  ulimit -a

Also for dual/multicore core machines, node.js is single threaded, it will not benefit from dual/multicores unless you use cluster to make use of it.